# How can you use TableView items to access View Controllers in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I'm attempting to create my first iOS app that I plan to publish into the App Store. It's a tabbed application with TableView embedded into each View Controller. Here's the code for one of my tabbed View Controllers:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AU: UITableViewController {

    var textArray = ["001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014", "015", "016", "017", "018", "019", "020", "021", "022", "023", "024", "025", "026", "027", "028", "029", "030", "031", "032", "033", "034", "035", "036", "037", "038", "039", "040", "041", "042" ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AUCell") as UITableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = textArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return textArray.count
    }
}
```

So, basically, when the user taps on one of the items in the `textArray`, I want to switch to a different View Controller. I'm currently writing this in Swift 2.

Answer (score 2):

Every `UIViewController` embedded in a `UITabBarController` has a reference back to the `UITabBarController` with its `tabBarController` property.  To change the selected view controller of the tab bar, set the tab bar's `selectedViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) { // check the row that was selected
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 // select a new tab on the tab bar, changing the selected view controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I'm not sure this is exactly what I'm looking for. I meant that it would send to a different View Controller that can't be otherwise accessed. I didn't mean switching between Tab Bars. Also, I went ahead and gave your code a try, and, after attempting to set up a storyboard ID to direct to, I ended up getting this error: Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Comment: Ah I see, so you want to instantiate a view controller either from a storyboard or xib and preset or push it.  In that case you would want to call pushViewController or presentViewController on self with the new VC you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a few ViewControllers in your main storyboard and give them **storyboard ids**

[image]

Create list of names :

```
let viewControllersNames = ["ViewController_1","ViewController_2","ViewController_3"]
```

and in the method :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(self.viewControllersNames[indexPath.row])
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for providing the code! I've successfully added it to my app, however, I'm not sure how I redirect to a specific View Controller. I'm a bit of a noob here when it comes to code in general, and I can only sort-of make out what the code means. The app successfully runs, however, I get the errors that two of my View Controllers (the two you mentioned to create) have no way of access.